# Functions redirect to webpage with XML request?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-functions, xmlhttprequest

In my webpage i am uploading a image to firebase functions and processing that image and then wanted to load into another webpage named `processed.html`. I am using hosting and functions together.

this is the xml request :

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", sFile);
    formData.append("quality", sQuality);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "/upload");
    ajax.send(formData);

function loadHandler(e) {
    //  
}

function errorHandler(e) {
    sFileLabel.innerHTML = e.target.responseText + 'Upload Failed';
}
```

What i need is that i want to open webpage after the response finsih.

for that i tried the res.redirect(`/processed?data=${base64data}`); in firebase functions but it didn't worked as the page itself didn't redirected just logged as  as xhr redirect response in network log. but no actual redirect of page.

how can i properly redirect to or load another webpage with that base64data as query so i can load that into that page.

Not loading the image in current page as other functionality provided in that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect means **what you asked for can be found *here* instead**.

A redirect **does not** mean *load this page in the browser's viewport*.

You made the request with `XMLHttpRequest`. The browser will follow the redirect, get the resource from the URL it was redirected to, and make that data available in the `response` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

If you want a redirect to be loaded in the viewport, then you need to make the original request using a method that would load the response in the viewport. e.g. **Use a regular form submission and do not involve `XMLHttpRequest`**.

---

If you want some logic that, depending on the response, *sometimes* modifies the current page with JS (`sFileLabel.innerHTML = e.target.responseText + 'Upload Failed'`) and *sometimes* navigates to a new page, then you need to trigger the navigation **with JS**.

```
location = "the new url"
```

Of course, you need to determine what the new URL is, and an HTTP redirect will be followed transparently by the browser, so you can't read the `Location` header to determine it.

That means you need to either **hard code** the URL client-side or **change the server-side code** so it returns data that the client-side JS can use to get the new URL. e.g. some JSON

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "success": true,
    "new_url: `/processed?data=${base64data}`
}
```

Comment: Okay gotcha. thanks a lot. one more question what is the alternative for that base64 data in query ? means don't want to send base64 data as query if possible. why ? because in case of bigger image that won't load.

Comment: I have found a post in quora which offers different alternatives to base64, remarking uuencoding which is similar to base64.
https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-alternatives-to-using-base64-encoding