# res.sendfile method in a post request does not render html page

Tags: javascript, express

When a user's registration is successful he is redirected to calendar.html

4 files are at play here

registration.html - triggers registration.js to check input

registration.js - triggers index.js to verify with database

index.js - Post request is triggered, if data id present in the database Get/calendar is triggered **(here is where the problem lies)**

calendar.html

in index.js

```
app.post("/register.html", async (req, res) => { 
    
    try { 
        console.log("erve")
        const {Username, Password, Email} = req.body 
        console.log(Username, Password, Email)

        const result = await users.insertMany({
            "Username": Username,
            "Email": Email,
            "Password": Password
        })
        console.log(__dirname);
        res.redirect(302, "calendar.html") 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("hi = ", error)
        res.status(201).send(error) 
    }
});


app.get("/calendar.html", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("at calendar")
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/calendar.html"); //<-- problem line
    res.status(200);

});
```

The problem is **The browser is receiving my file but not rendering it** how do I get my app.post to render it

Comment: How are you determining that the browser is receiving your file? What does the browser do with it if it doesn't render it?

Comment: @Quentin I checked the network tab, the post request does fetch calendar.html but stays on the register.html page

Comment: How are you making the request in the first place?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977680/functions-redirect-to-webpage-with-xml-request/63977810#63977810) your question?

Comment: @Quentin in register.js i fetch register.html with method post to trigger app.post,  Once i have created the necessary checks in app.post i redirect to the main page i.e calendar.html which triggers app.get

Comment: i haven't worked with ajax (this is an assignment) so i don't understand this

Comment: So it is a regular form submission? What does the browser display in the viewport if it isn't the HTML document?

Comment: it stays on the registration page

Comment: You have to wait for the reply from you back-end and then redirect to the received page or render it, depends on how you use it

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu i don't understand how that would help? the redirection works fine the send file is just not rendering the page